# Proper names for different representations of the same formula

Tags: notation, terminology, convention

I would like to know what to call formulas that are all on one line and what to call the same formulas that are on multiple lines.

One line example:  P ÷ TVD ÷ 0.052

Multiple line example: $\frac{P}{TVD \times 0.052}$

Make sense?  What is the proper terminology for each of these two different renderings?

THANKS!

Comment: Are you trying to write $\frac{P}{TVD \times 0.052}$? You can do this by typing this into your question: `$\frac{P}{TVD \times 0.052}$` (copy it exactly as shown). Also see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for more pointers on how to make questions with math formatted the way you want it.

Comment: Formulas using the $\div$ symbol are incredibly rare because it's not associative (your example could be read $P\div (TVD \div 0.052)$ or $(P \div TVD) \div 0.052$, which mean different things)

Comment: Thank you David, yes, that is exactly what I mean.  Thanks for showing me how to render it here.  I've made the edit.  But I'm much more interested in knowing what to call the beast than how to render it!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you Kopper.  Math is a big part of our courses but many of our students are pretty weak in it.  These folks look at the multiple line version and don't know what it means or what to do.  But when they see the "in-line" (?) version, they just go at it in a linear fashion.  (And just for my own curiosity:  wouldn't the priority of operators demand a linear approach anyway if there are no parentheses?  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "associative"...)

Comment: I've never heard of terms for distinguishing formulae based on how they are written.  Honestly, I doubt you'll find a term (would you expect there to be a term for formulae containing Greek characters?)

Comment: Someone temporarily answered (?) within a few minutes of my posting saying they thought the first was called "in line".  Yea, maybe there just isn't any conventional terminology for this difference.  Unless someone comes up with something "official", I think I'll just go with "in line" and "multi line" - definitely serves my purpose but I thought if there were "correct" terms, I'd like to use them!